# Python time stop UDP get data

Tags: python, sockets, text, udp

Code :

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import socket 
import struct 
import time

file_output = open('epg_python_raw.txt','w')

class EPG():    
    def open1():
        file_output = open('epg_python_raw.txt','w')
        MCAST_GRP = '238.1.1.1'
        MCAST_PORT = 1234

        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
        sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        sock.bind(('', MCAST_PORT)) 
        mreq = struct.pack("4sl", socket.inet_aton(MCAST_GRP), socket.INADDR_ANY)
        sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)

        while True:   
            data = sock.recv(10240)   
            print data
            print >> file_output, data
```

My question is, how can i stop this script after some time, I men limit exicution for a 5 min and exit. Btw I'm new into python so can you guys give me advice or some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this

```
t0 = time.time()
while time.time() - t0 < 300:   
    data = sock.recv(10240)   
    print data
    print >> file_output, data
```

i.e. check whether the seconds that passed since you started your while loop are less than 300 (five minutes).